# How do i define the task size in xTaskCreate()?

Tags: task, freertos, stack-size

I'm trying to write a simple code to blink the on board LED using the xTaskCreate() function. But i dont know what put in the stack size parameter

Answer (score 1):

The FreeRTOSConfig.h file provide a defined value configMINIMAL_STACK_SIZE.
This is a good starting point, especially for a such simple code (LED blinking).